# Cannot change color of SCNCone - Scenekit

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have an 'attach node' that has 2 child nodes that are Blender models. I have added a third node to this attach node that is a SCNCone. For some reason, I can't change the color of the cone node, only the transparency. I can't seem to see anything wrong with the code, but during runtime the cone is always a black color no matter what color I set it to.

```
let coneGeo = SCNCone(topRadius: 0.1, bottomRadius: 0.7, height: 4)
let coneMaterial = SCNMaterial()

coneMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 108.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 0.2)
coneGeo.materials = [coneMaterial]

let coneNode = SCNNode(geometry: coneGeo)
coneNode.position = SCNVector3(0, -1.5, 0)
coneNode.name = "coneNode"

AttachNode.addChildNode(coneNode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `coneMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 108.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 0.2)` with `coneGeo.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 108.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 0.2)`. Instead of changing the cone's material color without geometry, you have to access it's material color through it's geometry parameter.

Comment: Thank you! Doing `coneNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 108.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 0.2)` has done the trick. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
coneGeo.materials = [coneMaterial]
```

This will also work. I tested your code by adding the cone node to an empty scene.
I just get a black screen.

But if I change the alpha value to say `0.5`, this is what I get.

[image]

The code.

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene()

        let coneGeo = SCNCone(topRadius: 0.1, bottomRadius: 0.7, height: 4)
        let coneMaterial = SCNMaterial()

        coneMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 255.0 / 255.0,
                                                green: 108.0 / 255.0,
                                                blue: 91.0 / 255.0, alpha: 0.5)
        coneGeo.materials = [coneMaterial]

        let coneNode = SCNNode(geometry
                                   : coneGeo)
        coneNode.position = SCNVector3(0, -1.5, 0)
        coneNode.name = "coneNode"

        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(coneNode)

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

        // set the scene to the view
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
```

So I would say, check your alpha value in `UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 108.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 0.2)`